# Is there a BIP38 equivalent for Ethereum private keys?

Tags: clients, bitcoin, private-key, import, encryption

What is the best practice to encrypt an Ethereum private key? For example, Bitcoin has BIP38.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to comply with the [Web3 Secret Storage Definition.](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Web3-Secret-Storage-Definition)  This will allow your private key to be easily imported into clients such as Geth and cpp-ethereum (eth).  The definition encodes to a [JSON file](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1825/anatomy-of-a-geth-wallet-file) (unlike a Base58Check-encoded printable string as in BIP38) and includes test vectors.