# Anatomy of a Geth Wallet File

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, recovery

Just want to make sure I can fully recover a geth wallet. There are many parts to a typical wallet file:

```
{"address":"ethaddress",
"Crypto":{"cipher":"..aes","ciphertext...
```

So basically theres the :

1. address,
2. the ciphertext
3. the parameters
4. kdf & kdfparameters
5. mac address
6. and id.
7. version

What of that do I need to fully restore a wallet? All of it or are parts of it sufficient?

Comment: Restore from where? what you have in hand? `Mark Chester` s answer makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyfile follows the [Web3 Secret Storage Definition.](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Web3-Secret-Storage-Definition)

I believe the parts of the keyfile that are not necessary for account recovers are the `address` and `mac` value.  Technically the `version`, `cipher`, and `kdf` are not required since you could guess from the small set of possible choices for these.

### Private key recovery

The password you provide is used to derive an **encryption key** by passing it through a key derivation function or KDF.

Once the **encryption key** has been derived the *mac* value can be used to verify the key *(this step is optional)*

The **encryption key** can then be used to decrypt the **ciphertext** which will return the private key.

Answer (score -3):

The key file and your pasphrase

Comment: Yes, I understand that but when you have a paper wallet (print content of the keyfile) for example you can restore it using text only, so I wanted to better understand the anatomy.

Comment: @mashup I don't see why you can't print the JSON string or even encode the JSON string into a QR code if that's what you're after? (But you'll also need the passphrase.)