# What algorithm is used to encrypt a private key?

Tags: wallets, accounts, private-key, keystore, encryption

In my understanding, private keys are encrypted with some symmetric algorithm, so you can't access them without passphrase. What is it called?

Comment: This isn't specified in the standard. @CBobRobison is correct, Geth in particular uses AES to encrypt its private key, but this can varry from client to client. Most do use AES, because it's so ubiquitous

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1825/anatomy-of-a-geth-wallet-file

Comment: That can be looked up in the JSON file that stores the encrypted private key. It is typically the value of the `"cipher"` element. For example, in a Parity key file: `"cipher": "aes-128-ctr"` means 128-bit AES in Counter mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key is encrypted with 128-bit AES in Counter (CTR) mode.

Comment: How secure is this encryption method considering the improvement to computing power in the next 10 to 20 years?

Answer (score -3):

Private keys encryption is normally done using Sha algorithm.

Comment: SHA is not an encryption algorithm, it's a family of hash functions.