# How to generate a keystore (UTC) file from the raw private key?

Tags: private-key, nodejs, keystore, encryption

If I have the plaintext private key, -how- can I generate a `geth`-compatible keystore file using Node.js?

I think I need to encrypt it using the `scrypt` algorithm by supplying a password, but I don't know how to do this. Any -preferrably browserifiable- examples would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Simplest is to [import the key to Geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/465/how-to-import-a-plain-private-key-into-geth-or-mist) otherwise see http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1825/anatomy-of-a-geth-wallet-file

Comment: @eth Thanks! But I forgot to mention I want to do this in Node.js, without Geth. Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: I thought that was the case that's why I commented instead of answering :) Yes, it's a good idea to make questions more specific.  From the anatomy link you have the Web3 Secret Storage Definition and that might be enough to keep you going for a bit.  (I'd answer if I knew more.)

Comment: There's a [Python](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/develop/ethereum/keys.py#L117) library for what you want to do, if it helps.

Comment: You could also do in the desktop version of MyCrypto.com

Answer (score 14, accepted):

geth-compatible keystore file can be created in Node using [ethereumjs-wallet](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet) library:

```
> var Wallet = require('ethereumjs-wallet');
> var key = Buffer.from('efca4cdd31923b50f4214af5d2ae10e7ac45a5019e9431cc195482d707485378', 'hex');
> var wallet = Wallet.fromPrivateKey(key);
> wallet.toV3String('password');
'{"version":3,"id":"467233bf-45ec-423b-9548-bdc4a42aa099","address":"b14ab53e38da1c172f877dbc6d65e4a1b0474c3c","crypto":{"ciphertext":"17886b7ff355219dd20900543b9592fcd4dc6fe7d8f776f1a4d1c63993112181","cipherparams":{"iv":"434e4e71d2013a2d84e86a6e89efbb0b"},"cipher":"aes-128-ctr","kdf":"scrypt","kdfparams":{"dklen":32,"salt":"7a785ab75fa906734788d85ff43a2c8e704af41881dd50a2d52abe08092f07ec","n":262144,"r":8,"p":1},"mac":"98d9a76960dcef22a5fd28a6bf47e5c68a71b30bcf353eccbf5a6555abec78a1"}}'
```

You can also specify additional options to control kdf, cipher and other wallet params. See [here](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet#remarks-about-tov3).

Comment: Nice. I've used `geth account import privatekeyfile` to produce the following JSON `{"address":"b14ab53e38da1c172f877dbc6d65e4a1b0474c3c","crypto":{"cipher":"aes-128-ctr","ciphertext":"ff22d876d416cb97876dabfee6b6d00645de2d8dd5fca3b46f82112b1a3cffcd","cipherparams":{"iv":"798fcf346ea18c4c3c9e848118c94527"},"kdf":"scrypt","kdfparams":{"dklen":32,"n":262144,"p":1,"r":8,"salt":"bcc9bdc5a24f37ea56269017325b7bda67813199e017d566d7c274722a29d2b6"},"mac":"57efcea80420e75ed4087f20ac0e37481959a3a8a884e4c4a42bcb4331962dfc"},"id":"f162e70f-4b7c-425b-ba84-3041edfc292a","version":3}`