# How do I re-generate a lost Ethereum keystore file with only the Seed Phrase and Password?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, keystore

If I don't have the Ethereum Software Wallet Keystore anymore, but I recorded the Seed Phrase and Password:

How can I regenerate the keystore, if possible, and

Can it be done on a Windows machine if it was originally generated on an Ubuntu 16 install, and

Will I need to use the same program to regenerate the Keystore that I used to generate it?

I ask because anyone can create a Dummy Wallet and record info, to then test how to recover wallet access after deleting Keystore.

My question is:

What text command should I use to Re-generate a lost Ethereum Wallet Keystore using only the account's Seed Phrase and Password?

I don't understand what to do as described here:
[How to generate a keystore (UTC) file from the raw private key?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11166/how-to-generate-a-keystore-utc-file-from-the-raw-private-key)

Comment: The site @lungj mentioned works. However, finding one of any thousand or so of the derivations from only a seed phrase on My ether wallet would take dozens of hours. I recommend that if you have a password and seed phrase, write them both down and put it in a safe deposit box. Don't create superfluous wallets unless you're sure they won't be used.

Comment: You may find https://metasafe.org useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer.

Not sure what you mean by "text command", but you can use [www.MyEtherWallet.com](https://www.myetherwallet.com) (make sure you have the address correct; there are a lot of phishing sites) to use your wallet off-line using the seed phrase and password. This doesn't give you a keystore file. I'm guessing Parity, with its support for seed phrases, might also be of use.

Assuming your wallet software adhered to the BIP39 standard, any major wallet supporting seed phrases and passwords for those phrases should work, regardless of OS.