# Is it possible to import a Metamask account to Mist or Ethereum Wallet?

Tags: metamask

Is it possible to import a Metamask account to Mist or Ethereum Wallet? Metamask doesn't allow to export UTC file or json file, only pass phrase and private key and I don't see the option to import these in Mist or Ethereum wallet? Thanks.

Comment: See: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/465/how-to-import-a-plain-private-key-into-geth-or-mist

Comment: thanks! Please post an answer and I will check it solved.

Comment: I did geth account import „path to private key text file“
Everything seams to worked ok but my account doesn't show up in Ethereum Wallet nor Mist? When I try to run the command again it says „Account already exists…“. Am I doing something wrrong, how can I make it show up in ETH Walle tor Mist?
Thanks.

Comment: Check the `.ethereum/keystore` folder, if your account is there. If yes, Mist should pick the account.

Comment: It's not there at all... when try to run geth account import „path to private key text file“ again, I get an error saying: „Account already exists…“.

Comment: I'm really stupid, I ran cmd as an administrator so it put my account in my admin profile... I suppose I can just copy to my regular profile keystore...

Comment: It shows, it shows, thanks  Prashant Prabhakar Singh, please post an answer so I can close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is already answered [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/465/how-to-import-a-plain-private-key-into-geth-or-mist). Just for the shake of no link only answer.

DO the following steps to import your private key to geth and get a keystore  file:

- Open Notepad
- Paste key into notepad without any extra characters or quotations
- Save the file as nothing_special_delete_me.txt at C:\
- Run the command, geth account import C:\nothing_special_delete_me.txt
- After successful import, delete the file at
  C:\nothing_special_delete_me.txt

If you don't want to use or you don't have `geth`. You can create keystore file using `node` and [ethereumjs-wallet](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet) for same. (Ref: [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11166/how-to-generate-a-keystore-utc-file-from-the-raw-private-key))

```
var Wallet = require('ethereumjs-wallet');
var key = Buffer.from('efca4cdd31923b50f4214af5d2ae10e7ac45a5019e9431cc195482d707485378', 'hex');
var wallet = Wallet.fromPrivateKey(key);
wallet.toV3String('password');
```

The output of the last command is content of your keystore file. Just paste this in a json file and put this in `.ethereum/keystore` folder.